# React native and IBM Watson

Tags: node.js, react-native, ibm-watson

I have been using `expo` to build a react native app and would like to integrate an **IBM** Watson `chatbot` onto my platform. When I import the module however I receive a lot of error messages as core node modules such as *`os and fs seem to be missing`*, but aren't downloaded with *`node.js`* for some reason. When I try and add these manually, the *HTTPS* module is missing the *`index.js`* file. Is there any way for me to find this file or resolve this problem another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear from your question but I shall assume that you are using the [Node SDK for Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node). This is designed to be run in a Node.js environment which a react native JavaScript bundle is not (with or without expo). That's why you are missing key libraries like os and fs which the Node SDK expects. Installing fs won't resolve your problem because it also expects a Node.js environment to work, hence why there are [react native specific fs libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) that are able to use ios and android code to interact with the file system of the phone.

What you should be attempting is running the Node SDK on an independent server and running simple api requests using libraries like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or for more robust production systems [graphql](https://graphql.org/) so that your architecture will approximate this high level design.

[a high level architecture diagram which shows a phone connected by an arrow reading axios api request to another box labelled cloud hosted server. From this box another arrow labelled Node SDK is pointing to another box labelled Watson Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zAWU.png)

Web applications are similarly limited. The code run on the user's browsers can't directly use the Watson Assistant SDK, these requests to Watson Assistant need to be run by a server. There is an [example starter Watson Assistant web application](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple) that does this. If you run or host this application you can use the same server for your requests (although bear in mind this simple app and shared traffic probably isn't scalable for anything but a proof of concept).

So rather than running the api requests to Watson Assistant directly you run them to this domain of the server and then the necessary endpoint. The server in the example app is set up to accept requests to start the session at `<your domain>/api/session` and to send messages at `<your domain>/api/message`

You optionally can run direct api calls to Watson Assistant from a react native app without the SDK. It's not advisable because you would need to store your private keys on the device where they could be viewed by anyone.

Here is a functional component that is able to complete api calls direct to Watson Assistant using the v1 of the message tool without the SDK. BUT IT IS NOT ADVISED BECAUSE I MUST STORE MY KEYS INSECURELY.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import base64 from 'react-native-base64';

const workspace = ''; //replace with your own workspace id
const key = ''; //replace with your own key
const encodedKey = base64.encode(`apikey:${key}`);
// the following url will be different depending on where you host your Watson Assistant
// this is for Frankfurt as an example hence eu-de in the domain name
const assistantInstance =
  'https://api.eu-de.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/<This is your own>/v1'; //replace with your own

const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
  const sendMessage = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        `${assistantInstance}/workspaces/${workspace}/message?version=2018-09-20`,
        {
          input: { text: 'This is the message' },
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${encodedKey}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        },
      )
      .then((data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        setResponse('Got response');
      })
      .catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(err);
        setResponse('Got an error');
      });
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{response}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          sendMessage();
        }}
      >
        Send message
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

The next complication you will find is that you will need to add code to store the context returned in the response otherwise your state is lost. Your body would end up looking something like

```
        {
          input: { text: 'This is the message' },
          context: savedContextObject
        },
```

The newer version of the API has a stateful version which you may want to use instead. You can use this axios as a pattern for constructing whatever requests your prefer.

For the third and final time PLEASE DO NOT SAVE TO THE JS FILE YOUR API KEY as I do here. This is just as an example and for proof of concepts. Anyone who downloads your app will be able to unzip your apk and read these strings in your generated JS bundle unencrypted!